# Pre-trained FastText hyperparameters

Tags: nlp, fasttext

I'm using the pre-trained model:

```
import fasttext.util 
fasttext.util.download_model('en', if_exists='ignore') # English 
ft = fasttext.load_model('cc.en.300.bin')
```

Where can I find an exhaustive list of the values of the hyperparameters used to train the model?
https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/options.html list the default values, that differ from the used one: for example, the dimension of the word vectors is 300 and not 100 (citing https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/crawl-vectors.html that doesn't list them all).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Citing NVS Abhilash from https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/issues/887#issuecomment-649018188 the right code to write is:

```
args_obj = ft.f.getArgs()
for hparam in dir(args_obj):
    if not hparam.startswith('__'):
        print(f"{hparam} -> {getattr(args_obj, hparam)}")
```

This will print all the hyperparameters of the trained model!

Answer (score 1):

From looking at the `_FastText` Python model class in Facebook's source...

https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/blob/a20c0d27cd0ee88a25ea0433b7f03038cd728459/python/fasttext_module/fasttext/FastText.py#L99

...it looks like, at least when creating a model, all the hyperparameters are added as attributes on the object.

Have you checked if that's the case on your loaded model? For example, does `ft.dim` report 300, and other parameters like `ft.minCount` report anything interesting?

**Update:** As that didn't seem to work, it also looks like the `_FastText` model wraps an *internal* instance of a *native* (not-in-Python) FastText model in its `.f` attribute. (See a few lines up from the source code I pointed to earlier.)

And that native-instance is set up by the module specified by `fasttext_pybind.cc`. That code looks like it specified a bunch of read-write class variable, associated with the metaparameters - see for example starting at:

https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/blob/a20c0d27cd0ee88a25ea0433b7f03038cd728459/python/fasttext_module/fasttext/pybind/fasttext_pybind.cc#L88

So: does `ft.f.minCount` or `ft.f.dim` return anything useful from a post-loaded model `ft`?

Comment: Unfortunately, ft.minCount (as ft.dim) returns error: `_FastText' object has no attribute 'minCount'`, I don't know how could I check all the hyperparameters. This sounds like a silly question but I can't find any solution!

Comment: Sorry that didn't help; see my update in the answer for more things worth trying, based on a quick scan of the FastText Python-support source code.

Comment: The update didn't work either, I got the same error of `has no attribute`.
Luckily, I found the solution! Thank you anyway!

Comment: Aha, you have to look in the object returned by `ft.f.getArgs()`. Thanks for posting the solution you found.